# How to add control in mouse click point in WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel

I have a `WrapPanel` in my program that some button add to it in runtime (like the panel for add tags for question in this site). now I want to click between the buttons and add a new button in the place mouse is clicked.but I don't know how can I get mouse position between button or how to get child index of the button that placed before mouse click!

And I should to say I have to use `WrapPanel`, I dont want use `Canvas` or other container.

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `MouseClick` event of your `WrapPanel` :

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X-this.ClientSize.Width, MousePosition.Y-this.ClientSize.Height);
this.Controls.Add(b);
```

Update :

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X - this.ClientSize.Width, MousePosition.Y - this.ClientSize.Height);
this.WrapPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
```

Update 2 :

```
Button mybutton = new Button();
        mybutton.Content = "This is wpf button";
        Point mousePoint = this.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));  
        MainWindow win = new MainWindow();  
        win.Left = mousePoint.X;  
        win.Top = mousePoint.Y;
        mybutton.PointToScreen(new Point(win.Left,win.Top));
        wrapPanel1.Children.Add(mybutton);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but in wpf there isnt MouseClick for WrapPanel and location property for button. I think your code just works for WinForms.

Comment: I thought you were talking about WinForms. So see my Update

Comment: I write this code in MouseDown of WrapPanel and got this exception in line 7 :"This Visual is not connected to a PresentationSource"

Comment: do you know how can I get index of next or previous button in mouse click position ? if I find the Index my problem will be solved. thanks

Comment: int index = mybutton.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(mousepoint, true);

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by this code :

```
  private void wpContainer_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Button newButton = new Button()
                         {
                             Content= wpContainer.Children.Count,

                             Margin = new Thickness()
                             {
                                 Right = 10,

                                 Left = 10,
                             }
                         };

        var mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(wpContainer);

        int index=0;

        foreach (var child in wpContainer.Children)
        {
            Button currentButton = (child as Button);

            if (currentButton==null)
                continue;

            Point buttonPosition = currentButton.TransformToAncestor(wpContainer).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

            if (buttonPosition.X  > mousePosition.X && buttonPosition.Y+currentButton.ActualHeight > mousePosition.Y)
            {
                wpContainer.Children.Insert(index, newButton);

                return;                    
            }

            index++;
        }

        if(wpContainer.Children.Count==0 || index==wpContainer.Children.Count) //no items where detected so add it to the end of the Children
            wpContainer.Children.Add(newButton);
    }
```